# JBOSS came UP but GUI doesn't

Tags: java, jboss

Recently, we were facing some issues related to timesten configuration and as per Oracle's suggestion we gave a system reboot to verify the changes.

Post system reboot we found that one of our internal GUI ( related to the application ) didn't came up automatically. Although we restarted the JBOSS process manually post-reboot , process came UP well but GUI doesn't.

I went through the JBOSS startup.log as well but found to see so many errors there like:

1. error installing to real name=vfsfile jboss
2. org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: jboss:service=Hypersonic,database=localDB
3. ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss:database=localDB,service=Hypersonic state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
4. log4j error: setFile(null,true) call failed.
5. java.sql.SQLException: The database is already in use by another process: org.hsqldb.persist.NIOLockFile

........and many more

Literally, i have gone through every possible workaround available on internet with no success. Please pardon my question's framing methodology if it's sounds too be least technical.

I am new to JBOSS so need your help in resolving this issue.

Environment is Solaris 10 and JBOSS version is "jboss-5.1.0.GA"